# Adobe Flash IOS build TMS-90184: Invalid architectures

Tags: ios, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to publish Adobe flash iOS build to store but stuck with below error. I am using latest Adobe flash builder and ant to build the app. The Transporter doesn't complaint anything.

> ITMS-90184: Invalid architectures - This app has invalid architecture,
>   and may have been built with invalid build settings or incompatible
>   tools. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version. If you
>   are using third party development tools, contact the provider.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your flex SDK with air SDK 33.1
2. set MinimumOSVersion to 8.0 or higher (if build with ane, set it in platform.xml either)